# Ant doesn't find org.junit but it's right here(?)

Tags: java, ant, build, junit, jar

When trying to perform an `ant` build, I receive a message `package org.junit does not exist`. However, in `build.xml`, I have:

```
    <junit>
      <classpath>
        ... some stuff ...
    <fileset dir="dependlibs" includes="**/*.jar" />
      </classpath>
        ... other stuff ...
    </junit>
```

Now, in the same directory in which I am trying to run `ant` (the directory with `build.xml`), I have an `org` directory which contains `junit.jar`. Can Anyone point Me in the direction of information to show Me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that junit.jar is not in ants classpath. Provided your basedir is correct, you should be able to add it to the classpath by adding:

```
<junit>
   <classpath>
        <fileset dir="org">  
                <include name="**/*.jar" />  
        </fileset>  
   ....
   </classpath>
</junit>
```